# mysql getting specific entry not after INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have two variations of the same query:

```
SELECT * FROM jos_mls AS mls
    INNER JOIN jos_activeagents AS active ON mls.MSTLISTBRD = active.AGENTUID
    INNER JOIN jos_agents AS agents ON active.AGENTUID = agents.AGTBRDIDMM
    INNER JOIN jos_agencies AS firm on agents.AGTFRMID = firm.OFFFRMID
    AND mls.MSTRECAPDT >= ADDTIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), '04:29:00.000000');
```

And...

```
SELECT * FROM jos_mls AS mls
    INNER JOIN jos_activeagents AS active ON mls.MSTLISTBRD = active.AGENTUID
    INNER JOIN jos_agents AS agents ON active.AGENTUID = agents.AGTBRDIDMM
    INNER JOIN jos_agencies AS firm on agents.AGTFRMID = firm.OFFFRMID
    AND mls.MSTMLSNO = '4115762';
```

The first one works just fine, no problems.  The second is finding an entry based on a unique key.  However, it gives an empty set.  I can verify the the key exists, and when I run the first query, I know the column is being included in the set.

I have tried pulling it with and without quotes, with no luck.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you move your `AND mls...` clause up to the appropriate `ON` clause? ie for the `INNER JOIN ... ON mls...`.  Also, can you please provide the table def for `jos_mls` so we can see what type `MSTMLSNO` is?  How about `AND mls.MSTMLSNO LIKE '%4115762%';`?

Comment: `MSTMLSNO` is not the shared bey between `jos_mls` and `jos_activeagents`, so and `ON` clause wouldn't work.  I just don't get why it will pull for the one column but not the other.

Comment: Yes, it will work.  Doesn't need to be shared.  Proof? You ARE using this in _an_ on clause!  Just the wrong one.  You've `AND`ed it to the last `ON` clause for the final `JOIN` to `angencies`! ;-) Refer my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I suspect you meant to say `WHERE`, not `AND` ;-)

```
SELECT * FROM jos_mls AS mls

INNER JOIN jos_activeagents AS active ON mls.MSTLISTBRD = active.AGENTUID 
INNER JOIN jos_agents AS agents ON active.AGENTUID = agents.AGTBRDIDMM
INNER JOIN jos_agencies AS firm on agents.AGTFRMID = firm.OFFFRMID
WHERE mls.MSTMLSNO = 4115762
```

But what you've written is "valid" (in at least some DBMS, and I think OK in mysql).  But probably not "correct" in terms of the result you're after.

(I'm not especially familiar with mySql, but believe some DBMS have issue with expressions in `ON` clauses that are not related to the tables being `JOIN`ed at that point.  But my experience so far with mySql is this is *syntactically* fine)

And in some circumstances, even if it "works" (ie it runs and yields *some* result without error), the position of that clause will have an effect on the result set (I think) and on the query optimisation (I'm fairly sure).  One or both these things might be happening here?

Regardless of if it "fixes" the problem, IMHO you should move your `AND mls...` clause up to the appropriate `ON` clause for no other reason than readability/maintainability.

```
SELECT * FROM jos_mls AS mls

    INNER JOIN jos_activeagents AS active 
    ON mls.MSTLISTBRD = active.AGENTUID 
    AND mls.MSTMLSNO = 4115762

    INNER JOIN jos_agents AS agents ON active.AGENTUID = agents.AGTBRDIDMM
    INNER JOIN jos_agencies AS firm on agents.AGTFRMID = firm.OFFFRMID;
```

Comment: MSTMLSNO int(7), still nothing though.  Could it do a `WHERE` clause and then join the rest of the tables?

Comment: I do that and I still get an empty set, even when accounting for the trailing space.

Comment: @tPlummer Given your original query was possibly not returning what you expected it to return, do you have an accurate baseline?  What happens if you make the syntax changes (either move the `AND`, or change it to `WHERE`) to _both_ versions of your query? ie is it possible that this particular record you're chasing should never have made it into your first result set?

Comment: `WHERE` does not work in the first query.  I have verified the return from the first query as accurate.  I have moved the `AND` and changed it to `WHERE` in the second query, I either get a syntax error (where) or an empty set(and).

Comment: @tPlummer "WHERE does not work in the first query" - you mean you don't get the results you used to?  That doesn't mean it's not "working".  And you get a syntax error for using a `WHERE` in the second? Then you're not using it correctly :-) Rip out any remaining LIKE and percent signs, remove quotes from around your number.

Comment: @tPlummer If it's int(7), then clause should read `mls.MSTMLSNO = 4115762`

Answer (score 0):

EDITED FOLLOWING COMMENTS :

What happens when trying :

```
SELECT * FROM jos_mls AS mls WHERE mls.MSTMLSNO = 4115762;
```

Do you get any result ?

Comment: Are you suggesting a `LIKE` comparison? But you're still using an `=`.  Also, OP has since confirmed (in comments on my answer) that this field is an `int(7)`.

Comment: yep I updated my content given the new info. and indeed it should have been like and not "="

Comment: Good back-to-basics trouble-shooting step, I'd have been interested in the answer for this too. But prob. should've been a comment not an answer (although I realise you already had an answer on the go).  Welcome to SO by the way - I see you're doing really well in your first week!  Keep it up mate, good stuff.